# How to find Time Steps in LSTM?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp, lstm

I have a Bi-LSTM model and I want to get the computational complexity of it. I have read on internet that

> The computational complexity of learning LSTM models per weight and time step with the stochastic gradient descent (SGD) optimization technique is O(1). Therefore, the learn- ing computational complexity per time step is O(W).

But how do I find the time steps in my model? My model is

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_words, 768, input_length=max_len, weights=[embedding]))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(16)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.6))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax', use_bias=True, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(l1=1e-5, l2=1e-4), bias_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-4),
    activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-5)))
model.summary()
```

Model summary is

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 768, 768)          37147392  
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 768, 768)          3072      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 768, 768)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_1 (Bidirection (None, 32)                100480    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, 32)                128       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 32)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 32)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 66        
=================================================================
Total params: 37,251,138
Trainable params: 37,249,538
Non-trainable params: 1,600
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me. When you say "how do I find the time steps in my model", what specific concept do you mean by "time step" Because time steps do not exist as an actual variable, instead you have the weight matrix or hidden state that get updated at each timestep. In addition, none of this has anything to do with theoretical bounds?

Comment: In this specific case, the number of timesteps is given by the Embedding layer, in particular the input_length parameter

Comment: @runDOSrun I want to find the computational complexity of my model. And as quoted, it depends on time step. So, how do I find the complexity that's the question.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy so `max_len` will be the number of time steps? And as quoted, the comutational complexity depends on weight. And my weight matrix is 768 x 48639 (in dimensions). So, will the computational complexity will be the product of dimensions multiplied by number of timesteps?

Comment: @AmberBhanarkar A computational complexity O(N) is a bound that specifies behavior for growing N. Calculating **a single** N doesn't really tell you anything about the complexity. If it is O(W) for each t, then it is `O(W*T)` in total for all timesteps. But again, setting numbers into W or T isn't doing anything.